# Why is it so difficult to sample from a Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-physics, sampling, statistical-mechanics

I am studying simulated annealing, and simulated annealing involves a Boltzmann distribution.

Typically I see the Boltzmann distribution written like:

$P(E_i) = e^{-E_i/(kT)}/Z$

where $Z$ is the sum of all of the energy in all of the states, and $P(E_i)$ is the energy in just one of the states.

The thing is in simulated annealing I see the pdf written with an integral:

$P(x) = \frac{e^{-f(x)/T}}{\int_{S}e^{-f(z)/T}dz}$

I understand from many sources that the Boltzmann distribution is reportedly very difficult to sample from because it involves this $f(z)$ as you can see above.  I have two questions about that:

1) Why does the $f(z)$ not appear in the first equation I gave for the Boltzmann distribution?  (e.g., it does not appear here on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell–Boltzmann_distribution)

2) I'm able to fire up python and use `scipy` to easily sample from a Boltzmann distribution just by doing

`import scipy
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r = scipy.stats.boltzmann.rvs(lambda_=1.4, N=4, size=10)`

without trouble.  (source: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boltzmann.html#id23)

So what is the big deal with sampling from a Boltzmann distribution?  There are all these fancy methods in Simulated Annealing like Hit and Run, Metropolis sampling, etc.

Why are they necessary when I was able to sample from a Boltzmann distribution with ease?

Comment: Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution $\not=$ Boltzmann distribution

Comment: Ah, that's key thank you!!  Do you care to explain @Winther why the same formula that i hve above is also is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution ?

Answer (score 1):

In the first equation, $f(z)$ is represented by $E_i $. This term is used to represent the energy repartition. It is just a continuous version of the Boltzmann disitribution (and not Maxwell-Boltzmann, which is a different law).

In addition, the main problem is the computation of $Z$.

In most pratical problems requiring such distribution, the number of states is enormous, and each of them has his proper energy.

Imagine you want to find the shortest way to travel through $N$ cities, you have to pass only once by city and finish by the one you started from. Then, you have $0.5(N-1)!$ possibilities. For $N=20$ only, you already have about $6\times10^{16}$ different states to consider.

This is why we need algorithms such as Metropolis, to avoid having to compute $Z$.

Comment: i was thinking the denominator represents the number of cities, rather than the number of possible paths, and the numerator represents one city.  my understanding is wrong then?

Comment: I am not completely understanding how metropolis solves this.  from wiki page on Metropolis-Hastings:  "the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm can draw samples from any probability distribution P(x), provided you can compute the value of a function f(x) that is proportional to the density of P. The last requirement that f(x) should be merely proportional to the density, rather than exactly equal to it..."  But how are we going to know the proportion?

Comment: Furthermore, why is scipy able to easily give me an answer?

Comment: Here a "state" is a path since you want to find the best path (i.e. the path with the minimum length/energy). The thing is, for the Metropolis algorithm, you will never know the proportion of energy taken by each state, since the algorithm does not compute $Z$. Finaly, the scipy function you used compute a "truncated discrete exponential", which is quite different. And you used it for a small state space. Imagine having to go through $N$ states with $N$ being about $10^{16}$ to compute the distribution, it will be quite long (and $20$ cities is still a reasonable number).

Comment: For the [Metropolis-Hastings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) if you will "never know the proportion of energy taken by each state", as you say, then how is it able to get a reasonable approximation to the Boltzmann distribution? @nicomezi

Comment: Depends on what you call reasonable. In a "real" run of the algorithm, you will only pass through a very small number of states (relatively to the total number of states itself). You would need a very very long time to get a "reasonnable" approximation of the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You may either have quantised energies or continuum of energies in your system. If you have a discrete set $\{E_{k}\}_{k}$ where $k$ is some index tuple (e.g. quantised energy, quantised angular momentum, spin, isospin etc....), Boltzmann says that a probability for a system to be be in the state characterised by $E_{k}$ is given by
$$p_{k}=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta{E}_{k}}$$
Where the normalization $Z$, known as the partition function is given by
$$Z(\beta)=\sum_{\forall{k}}e^{-\beta{E}_{k}}$$
An example of a system may be a spin-$1/2$ particle in a harmonic trap then $k=(n, \sigma)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ and $\sigma\in\{-1/2, 1/2\}$ and $E_{n, \sigma}=\omega(n+1/2)$. On the other hand, one may have a system with continuum of energy $\{E({k})\}_{k}$ where $k$ now belongs to some uncountable set, in that case, Boltzmann says that a probability to find the system in the infinitesimal energy window $[k, k+dk]$ is given by
$$p(k)=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta{E}(k)}dk$$
With
$$Z(\beta)=\int_{\forall{k}}e^{-\beta{E}(k)}dk$$
Example may be a particle on $1D$ lattice with nearest neighbour hopping, then $E(k)=E_{0}-\alpha\cos{k}$, where $k\in[-\pi, \pi]$. And you also may have a mixed situation. E.g. some of the indices are discrete and some are continuous, then you have to sum over discrete and integrate over continuum.

Comment: This is very good, thank you @KirylPesotski.  I understand that.  But in Python I am able to easily sample from a Boltzmann distribution simply by setting lambda and N, as indicated here: https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.boltzmann.html.  So, I'm wondering why some pieces of literature think it is so difficult to sample from the Boltzmann distribution that they have all these fancy methods like hit and run and MCMC.  Why are those necessary?  thanks.